# Mostrar mensaje al saltar excepción de escáner c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, visual-studio-2019

He creado una tabla en mi base de datos en la que almaceno los códigos de error de un escáner y sus descripciones, y quiero que me muestre un mensaje con ellos cada vez que detecte un error.

Uso Visual Studio 2019 y SQL Server.

El método que uso para las excepciones es el siguiente, pero no entra en el while, por lo que no muestra nada:

```
public static void excepciones(COMException er)
{
   string errorCode = er.ErrorCode.ToString();
   string codigo, error, desc;

   SqlCommand buscar = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE codigo = @errorCode;", con);
   buscar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@errorCode", errorCode);
   
   con.Open();

   SqlDataReader reader = buscar.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
     codigo = reader["codigo"].ToString();
     desc = reader["descripcion"].ToString();

     MessageBox.Show(desc, "Código: " + codigo + "\t Error: " + error + "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
   }

   con.Close();
}
```

También he intentado poner  `codigo = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(); desc = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();` sustituyendo el código del while, pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Seria bueno hacer un debug, para verificar que este haciendo la búsqueda según el código...

Comment: @TheOligarch parece que ```SqlDataReader reader = buscar.ExecuteReader();``` no guarda nada.

Comment: Creo que el error puede estar en ```string errorCode = er.ErrorCode.ToString();```, parece que no guarda bien el error, por lo que no lo encontraría el ```buscar```. He sustituido esa línea por ```uint errorCode = (uint)er.ErrorCode;```, pero no sé que tipo tengo que poner en mi base de datos para la columna ```codigo```.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! si tranformaste el codigo a numero, entonces en tu base de datos deberia ser un numero... no?

Comment: @gbianchi En la base de datos he cambiado el tipo de dato a int, bigint y otros tipos numéricos, pero con todos me da este error: The parameter data type of UInt32 is invalid.

Comment: La propiedad ErrorCode de objeto COMException  es de tipo entero, pero tu lo puedes guardar como cadena en tu base de datos, no tendrías que tener ningún problema con eso.

Comment: porque usas un UINT, que es un entero sin signo? los errores a veces son numeros negativos...

Comment: @TheOligarch Lo estaba guardando en la base de datos como varchar y después convirtiendo el error del escáner a string, pero como no me funciona así he intentado cambiarlo a int.

Comment: @gbianchi Uso un UINT porque no he visto que se use ```errorCode``` con otro tipo, por lo que pensaba que solo podía usar UINT. Voy a probar a guardarlo como INT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código estaba prácticamente bien, he cambiado el tipo de `codigo` en la base de datos a bigint y la sentencia `buscar.Parameters.Add`, en la que convierto el errorCode en `Int32`

```
public static void excepciones(COMException er)
{

   int errorCode = Math.Abs(er.ErrorCode);
   string codigo, error, desc;

   SqlCommand buscar = new SqlCommand("SELECT codigo, descripcion FROM tabla WHERE codigo = @errorCode;", con);
   buscar.Parameters.Add("@errorCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(errorCode);

   con.Open();

   SqlDataReader reader = buscar.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
     codigo = reader["codigo"].ToString();
     desc = reader["descripcion"].ToString();

     MessageBox.Show(desc, "Código: " + codigo, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
   }

   con.Close();
}
```